# Panasonic CF-19 MK1 toughbook sound issue. Headphones work but internal speaker doesn't

Tags: sound

I've tried to breathe new life into my aging CF-19 MK1 by loading elemenary rather than Windows which it was struggling with.
Its a nice looking OS and everything important works except the sound. If I plug in headphones it works ok but if I try to use the computers speaker nothing happens. Even tried connecting to a bluetooth speaker and that doesn't work either. Alsa mixer shows the volumes turned up. In settings it only shows onboard sound and in stereo. There is only a mono speaker in the computer.
Have tried Linux Mint as well and that has the same issues. 
New to Linux and not too sure where to go from here, any help would be gratefully recieved.